# How to get full business opening hours in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

Some businesses share their opening/closing times on their own POI on Google Maps.

The web interface in my browser shows the times for the current week *only* (and when they were last updated). However, I am interested in knowing if the business has set different opening times for other periods (other months, weeks, times of the year...).

**How can I get the full opening time schedule for this business?** Is it even possible?

Comment: Please search https://support.google.com/maps, share what you found and why it didn't meet your needs.

Comment: @Rubén I found [this](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/7084895?hl=en) and the animated gif doesn't seem to allow defining opening hours for different periods of the year. Nevertheless, I sometimes saw on Google Maps different times depending of the year (like temporary closed for a few weeks for holidays). Also API is not necessarily "web development", a special URL in the browser can sometimes do things that are not available on the classic web interface (example: getting elevation from lat/long on GMaps is possible via a special URL outside the webapp).

Comment: Unfortunatelly terms like "API" atracts off-topic question. If they are really required, please provide context (it should be clear that the use of the API is as end user, i.e. using specific online IDE for scripting like Google Apps Script rather than using cURL from local terminal). Just be careful to keep the question focused.

Comment: @Rubén do I get it right that, in the way you see the world, "online IDE for scripting" is a "usage as end user" while "cURL in terminal" is not? Otherwise, I was just thinking about a (customised?) URL in the browser, possibly returning a JSON or some other kind of text-based answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it's possible.  Businesses can only set a limited set of operating hours.  See Image.  It would be rather cumbersome to show all the hours they may have set.  I couldn't find anything on [Google Search Help](https://support.google.com/websearch/?hl=en#topic=3081620) for time display.

It automatically shows the relevant hours.  I have my business on it and before the local holidays, it sends me a message about updating the opening hours.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes it pretty clear how it works internally, especially when you say "before the local holidays, it sends me a message about updating the opening hours". And if you set "holidays opening hours" as I see on the screenshot, is that something a lambda user can see? (I mean, would it be possible for a user, then, to display both the "normal" opening hours alongside the "holiday opening hours"?)